# How to overcome the error of "Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature"?

Tags: swift, generics, realm

I'm trying to convert the following to be generic.

```
extension RLMOrganization: DataProvider {

    func getLastSyncToken() -> String {
        let lastUpdated: RLMOrganization? = self.findAll(sortedBy: "syncToken").last

        if let syncToken = lastUpdated?.syncToken {
            return syncToken
        } else {
            return "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    }


}
```

And have tried this:

```
protocol DataProvider: DatabaseLayer {
    associatedtype T: Object

    func findAll<T: Object>(sortedBy key: String) -> [T]
}

extension DataProvider {

func findAll<T: Object>(sortedBy key: String) -> [T] {
    let database = self.getDatabase()

    if let allObjects = database?.objects(T.self) {
        let results = allObjects.sorted(byKeyPath: key, ascending: true)
        return Array(results)
    }

    return []
}


    func getLastSyncToken<T: Object>() -> String {
        let lastUpdated = self.findAll(sortedBy: "syncToken").last as? T

        if let value = lastUpdated?.value(forKey: "syncToken") {  // get value from object by string name
            let syncToken = value as! String
            return syncToken
        } else {
            return "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    }

...
```

But can't seem to overcome the error of:

> Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature

[image]

I would think the compiler has everything it needs to determine *type* usage.

Comment: Please provide enough code to compile. Without a definition of DatabaseLayer, your code cannot be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below works for me, I don't know how `findAll` is defined but the problem is the reference to self as I see it so you need to define T there using `associatedtype`.

```
protocol DataProvider: DatabaseLayer {
    associatedtype T: Object

    func findAll(sortedBy: String) -> T?
}
```

Comment: @SebastianDwornik You don't have to make the method generic, you just use the associated type when needed.